# Necessity of Windows OS

Tags: networking, windows-10

I currently have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 in my laptop. I'm going to start learning Networking concepts very soon. I'm an avid Linux user and have really no use for windows OS for my development projects. So my question is, is windows OS really necessary to learn networking concepts? Do I have to keep it? Because I'm thinking of completely deleting Windows from my system and only keep the the Linux one. I'm a newbie to networking field, so please guide me.

Comment: Since we do not know in what field or environment your networking skills will be used, the question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 2):

Every system is worth learning if you want to be versatile. Now if your going to specialize in linux only systems, then you don't need Windows else if your training will include all networks in general, you will definitely need Windows to do that.

It depends on your intended area of specialization. Look at your course work and see if you need it, ask your course provider they will better inform you on what is needed.

Comment: The certifications that I have lined up are - A+, N+, CCNA, RedHat certfications, Microsoft Certifications, Ethical Hacking, System Security and Cloud Computing. Based on this, would you say I need Windows? (for the Microsoft ones, I know I do need the OS, but I really dislike having it in my system; very bulky, always some or the other updates, etc).

Comment: Like I said and from your comment you need it, but if you can afford then install on a different system as hard ware use in the certification process matters

Answer (score 1):

While there are some networking technologies that are specific to Windows, the vast majority of technologies and concepts are agnostic to the operating system. So I'd say you don't *need* to keep Windows. But it probably won't hurt to have a Windows installation up your sleeve, in case the need to use pops up some time later.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought too. Will running Windows 10 on VirtualBox suffice?

Comment: @VinooBharadwaj no it will not suffice. Access to hardware is usually not full when using a VM!

Comment: Ah.. thanks for the input! Looks like I will have to keep both of them for a while till I get a hand at the core concepts.